# Generate parent pom for existing project modules

Tags: maven, parent-pom

I have following project modules. Each of the modules have their own `pom.xml` . Now I want to generate a parent POM (for existing modules like below) . Is there a way to do that? I know there is a way we can do if we are creating brand new project but my need here is I already have a project structure.

1. `project-module-1`
2. `project-module-2`
3. `project-module-3`
4. `project-module-4`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need revising your exising project a little, it is not too hard.

Your project structure like this

[image]

parent `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>sample</description>
    <url>http://example.com</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>project-module-1</module>
        <module>project-module-2</module>
        <module>project-module-3</module>
        <module>project-module-4</module>        
    </modules>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Child `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-module-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>sample</description>
    <url>http://example.com</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Sample project source code: https://github.com/donhuvy/maven_parent_childs/archive/master.zip